# Regular expression tag matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have a very simple Perl function that returns the content of a tag in custom XML code I need to parse. However, if there are line returns inside of the tags, then it returns an empty value and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
sub in_tag
{
    my ($text, $tag) = @_;
    my ($content) = $text =~ m/<$tag.*>(.*)<\/$tag>/;
    $content = $content . "";
    return $content;
}

# works
print in_tag("<item><creation type=\"date\">2014-01-03</creation><name type=\"word\">John Doe</name><id type=\"number\">67</id></item>", "name");

# doesnt work
print in_tag("<item><creation type=\"date\">2014-01-03</creation><name type=\"word\">John\nDoe</name><id type=\"number\">67</id></item>", "name");
```

Comment: Use a proper XML handling module like [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig)...

Comment: are you sure there can never ever be a `>` in an attribute value? `<tag att="a>b"> is a valid XML tag

Comment: By the way the reason I don't use a set module is because I'm dealing with specific input that is considered invalid XML by those modules, hence the need for a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `.` regex metacharacter match a newline, you need to use the `/s` flag:

```
m/..../s;
```

You also want to use non-greedy quantifiers in your regular expression. Put a `?` after the `*` to still match zero or more, but with the provision that it doesn't go beyond text that would match the next part of the pattern:

```
m/<$tag.*?>(.*?)<\/$tag>/
```

I don't mind this simple sort of extraction for quick programs or small, uncomplicated inputs, but beyond that I like [XML::Twig](http://www.metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig). It takes a bit to get used to, but once you get the hang of it you'll be able to do all sorts of fancy things with almost no effort.